# Why is it not possible to use a static IP address within the docker deafult bridge?

Tags: networking, ip, docker

If I want to use a static IP for my container I must declare my own network and start the container with `--net mynet0 --ip 172.16.0.2`.

Why is it not possible to use a static IP address within the docker deafult bridge? Why so cumbersome making me create a new network?

Comment: It's a bit confusing. You have IP assigned to the bridge and you expect, that the same IP could be used in the container too?

Comment: Yeah ok, sorry for that: I want to have a static IPs in the default Bridge and that's not possible. But I can only use static IPs within an user-defined network. A static IP within the default Bridge, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a default bridge ip by either editing `/etc/docker/daemon.json` or starting the daemon with flag `--bip=<ip>/<cidr>`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

Comment: Sorry man I'm not talking about a default bridge IP, I'm talking about a static IP for a container in the default bridge.